# Could this <form> element be hindering our rankings?

Tags: seo

I've recently taken over the development of a website and have been fixing their on-page content, restructuring their title tags and rehashing their content etc

I've come across this piece of code in their markup across all pages, could it be possible that this could be holding back our rankings?

Obviously i don't expect to correct the code and see a 4 page jump but I don't want this to be hindering our potential ranking-wise

The code is below

```
<body id="htmlbody" style="margin: 0px;">
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Translator.aspx?Name=business-cards" id="aspnetForm">
```

The whole markup of the web page is wrapped within that form tag, before the closing body tag their is the closing form tag.

Obviously this is bad code practice and I'm still waiting on a response from the developers but my feeling is that when GoogleBot crawls our pages, it isn't liking what it comes across.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way ASP.NET web forms works. The entire page is wrapped within a form tag. It will not affect your SEO ranking in any way.

Although one might argue that it's bad practice, you will find an enormous amount of sites out there that have this form wrapping their content.

[This SO answer will](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038217/why-does-asp-net-wrap-the-page-in-a-form) give you more information as to why the form tag exists.